# Matlab: How to use Neural Network Toolbox with Command Line (not GUI)

Tags: linux, matlab, user-interface, neural-network

I need to make a neural network to fit some data, a very large set of data, and my laptop is not powerful enough to use the training tools in the Neural Network Toolbox. I have access to a nice Linux cluster with Matlab, but the compute nodes don't do X11, so I can only use command line or script.

After reading the [Mathworks page on Using Neural Network Toolbox](http://www.mathworks.com/help/nnet/gs/using-neural-network-toolbox.html), it looks like it should be possible to harness the functionality of tools such as `nftool` from the command line, but even after looking at the [Getting Started Guide](http://www.mathworks.com/help/pdf_doc/nnet/nnet_gs.pdf) and the [User's Guide](http://www.mathworks.com/help/pdf_doc/nnet/nnet_ug.pdf), I found no understandable instructions of how to start calling commands to the NNT without bringing up a GUI.

The closest was on page 20 of the User's Guide, in the third paragraph, where it says that reading the code of the GUI tools provides a good introduction to using the toolbox by command line. However, the code (found in C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2016a\toolbox\nnet) contains a lot of references to commands I'm not familiar with, particularly running Java from within Matlab.

Despite having used the `nftool` several times, I do not recognize any of the lines as "Ah, this is what does that". So, I guess what I'm looking for is a set of instructions that connect the commands to what they do.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the NN UI first, it can generate the matlab code for you, as an example. There is no simple answer to your question as the NN toolbox has quite a large array of functionality, so essentially the answer would be a complete tutorial.

http://www.mathworks.com/help/nnet/gs/fit-data-with-a-neural-network.html#f9-33554.

In fact if you click that link, the advice is precisely what I was saying above.

After stepping through the nftool (or similar) screens, don't stop at the Deploy screen, keep going by clicking next to the final 'Save' screen and choose simple or advanced scripts.
[image]

Comment: Sorry, I didn't make it clear, I have already made a few neural networks of a similar structure to what I want, but what I really want from the toolbox is training for the specific data values. (I'll add that to the question.)

Comment: Have added more to the answer, hopefully that gets you going

Comment: You can also try 'help fitnet' at the command prompt and it will tell you how to do what you want from the command prompt.